# Can I run multi version of Nodejs in Linux without using NVM

Tags: node.js

I have a Node installed in my PC with v8.x.

Now I want to use Node v12.x, I heard it was shipped with
tls_event_keylog
https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_event_keylog_1 which is pretty cool, because it can be used it to debug TLS connection.

I did a lot of research on Google but all articles that I found is using NVM.

But I do not want to use NVM, I am afraid about it can break my environment.

So can you please help me to resolve it, thanks!

I tried to do some research on Google but unsuccessfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use nave, a shell script created by isaacs:
https://github.com/isaacs/nave

Very similar to nvm, but I think it is a lightweight solution comparatively.  Works for me under several distros.

Obviously won't work under windows, so I use a windows variant of nvm (not associated with the Linux version from what I recall).

Answer (score 0):

I think Docker is a rescue, it is easy to switch between versions and we can use volume to store node packages!